# Makefile: Exist a way to pass an argument in the terminal as my target?

Tags: c, makefile

For example I want to type in terminal:

make name

and make compile and runs the name.c file without the need to specify the rule "name" in the makefile.

Comment: make (at least GNU make) will do exactly that even with no makefile at all.

Comment: LOL, exist an way to specify the directory where I will create the .o file? make name will create name.o in the same directory.

Comment: If you don't want the object file or executable created in the current directory, or the source is located elsewhere, you need a makefile to configure the non-default behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want object files to go in some other directory you'll have to create a makefile with new rules describing that.  Something like this:

```
OBJDIR = obj

%: %.o
%: $(OBJDIR)/%.o
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
        $(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<
```

The `%: %.o` line deletes the built-in rule.